# problem with scrollview

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

I am having view this comes from push view controller through navigation.this view has scroll view,when i run the project view is not scrolling.how do i make it scroll.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set content size for that view.

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width,TOTAL_HEIGHT_TO_DISPLAY_CONTENT);
```

Hope this helps.

Jim.

Comment: just for testing purpose set TOTAL_HEIGHT_TO_DISPLAY_CONTENT to 500.It will work.but later on you will have to set TOTAL_HEIGHT_TO_DISPLAY_CONTENT as per content you are displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the [content size](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentSize) of the scroll view? Set it to the size of what the scroll view contains.

Comment: yeh,i already defined content size with height=650 and width =320.